# Hi guys. I get error below whenever I'm typing 'make' command in order to install my project. your help much appreciated

Tags: make

```
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
Making all in thesis
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos/doc/thesis'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos'
fig2dev -L pstex_t -p virtmem_half virtmem_half.fig virtmem_half.inc
/bin/bash: fig2dev: command not found
make[2]: *** [virtmem_half.inc] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos/doc/thesis'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/enas/Desktop/speedos-0.2.0/speedos/doc'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 5):

make tries to run the command `fig2dev` but it's not available on your system.

Install the package `transfig`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. could you please write the complete command I'm very new with system?

Comment: @Eno:  `sudo apt-get install transfig`

Comment: I finished with the package but once I typed the command i got this error sudo: ./fig2dev: command not found

Comment: It's just `fig2dev` without the `./`. But you don't need to call it yourself, make will do that.

Comment: yes sir I got it. but still i have problem with "make" now I got this new error when I typed it.(shown below)
! LaTeX Error: File `mypsfonts.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

Comment: A file named `mypsfonts.sty` is missing. There isd no such file in any package in the Ubuntu repository. Maybe the program’s documentation can tell you where to get this file.

Comment: Ok sir I will locate within the program’s documentation as you recommended, but I don't know what should I do if its not there... many thanks sir.

Comment: Most probably you need to fix your latex stuff where this file is defined.

Comment: Thx Mr Phillip for answering. Could you tell me please what do you mean exactly by my latex stuff ? Where is that ? And how ?

Comment: Hi guys. Error : a file named mypsfonts.sty is still missing ! where can I find it? How? I cant run "make" command because of it!

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion.

Comment: Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S fig2dev`